# Convert String data in Row Data for Google Chart DataTable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-visualization

I need Use String as data for Google Charts.

If I use manual data to set the rows, the chart works:

```
data.addRows([['1',327,41],['2',284,16],['3',305,46],['4',462,47],['5',214,68],['6',221,37],['7',227,13],['8',235,42],['9',179,5],['10',591,28],['11',405,27]]);
```

See sample works:
Please: [See](http://cbrainmx.com/NoEnCasa/gr.asp)

But, I use dinamically String created on the fly as string:

```
Var Data="[['1',327,41],['2',284,16],['3',305,46],['4',462,47],['5',214,68],['6',221,37],['7',227,13],['8',235,42],['9',179,5],['10',591,28],['11',405,27]]"
```

And I try to use it as indicated:

```
data.addRows(data);
```

but this has no result, no chart is created.
Please: [See](http://cbrainmx.com/NoEnCasa/gr2.asp)

So I've tryied:

```
var json = JSON.parse(datos);
data.addRows(json);
```

And No result
Please: [See](http://cbrainmx.com/NoEnCasa/gr3.asp)

Could You help me?

Comment: you can create a data table from a json string, if you use this particular format --> [Format of the DataTable Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use `eval()`

```js
var a = [1,2,3]
console.log(Array.isArray(a))

var a = "[1,2,3]";
console.log(Array.isArray(a))

var a = eval("[1,2,3]");
console.log(Array.isArray(a))
```